# Asp.Net/ IIS while saving record date coming in Chinese

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7

In my Asp.Net application when I save or update a record the date is coming as ***@CreatedAt = N'06-May-2015 02:49:03 下午*** only the AM/PM part is coming in chinese while in systems *Region and language* setting Format is *English* and Location is Macau S.A.R. The Webapplication also supports *Chinese* language through Globalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the CurrentCulture property is not being set to zh-CHT (or something equivalent) either in your Web.config or the Page where the record is being saved in code.

Comment: Hi Ramon, the CurrentCulture property is always set to "en-US". is it possible any setting changed in IIS?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Double check the culture in IIS by opening IIS manager and clicking on .NET Globalization on the home screen (under ASP.NET). Make sure it doesn't say anything besides Invariant Language or en-us. Also check your culture in Internet Explorer under settings. I know ASP.NET sites also get their settings from their.

Comment: Hi Ramon, before it was "Invariant Language" now it is changed to "en-US" and it worked thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Go to IIS -> .NET Globalization and check the culture there. Make sure it is Invariant. Check the below screen shot

Check below in IIS setup

[image]